# Observe change on a @Published var in Swift Combine after didSet?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Let's say that we have a following code written in Swift that uses Combine:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class Test {
  @Published var array: [Int] = [] {
    willSet {
      print("willSet \(newValue.count)")
    }
    didSet {
      print("didSet \(array.count)")
    }
  }
}

var test = Test()
var subscriber = test.$array.sink { values in
  print("arrayCount: \(test.array.count) valuesCount: \(values.count)")
}

print("1 arrayCount \(test.array.count)")
test.array = [1, 2, 3]
print("2 arrayCount \(test.array.count)")
test.array = [1]
print("3 arrayCount \(test.array.count)")
```

This code prints following result on the console (it can be quickly tested in playground):

```
arrayCount: 0 valuesCount: 0
1 arrayCount 0
willSet 3
arrayCount: 0 valuesCount: 3
didSet 3
2 arrayCount 3
willSet 1
arrayCount: 3 valuesCount: 1
didSet 1
3 arrayCount 1
```

As we can see the code given to sink method is executed after willSet and before didSet of given property. Now my question is: is there any way to create this publisher or subscribe to it in such way that the code given to sink is executed after didSet and not before it (so that arrayCount and valuesCount would be the same when print from sink is executed in above example)?

Comment: An `@Published` property calls `send` in `willSet`. You would need to create your own publisher and call `send` in `didSet` yourself instead of using `@Published`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Published.Publisher` uses `willSet` to emit values for the wrapped property. Unfortunately you cannot change this behaviour, the only solution is to implement your own property wrapper that uses `didSet` instead of `willSet`.

You can also customise whether you want to receive the current value when subscribing to the `projectValue` publisher (matching the `@Published` behaviour), using the `emitCurrentValue` input argument. If it is set to `true`, the current `wrappedValue` is sent to new subscribers on subscription.

```
/// A type that publishes changes about its `wrappedValue` property _after_ the property has changed (using `didSet` semantics).
/// Reimplementation of `Combine.Published`, which uses `willSet` semantics.
@available(iOS 13, *)
@propertyWrapper
public class PostPublished<Value> {
  /// A `Publisher` that emits the new value of `wrappedValue` _after it was_ mutated (using `didSet` semantics).
  public let projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Value, Never>
  /// A `Publisher` that fires whenever `wrappedValue` _was_ mutated. To access the new value of `wrappedValue`, access `wrappedValue` directly, this `Publisher` only signals a change, it doesn't contain the changed value.
  public let valueDidChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>
  private let didChangeSubject: any Subject<Value, Never>
  public var wrappedValue: Value {
    didSet {
      didChangeSubject.send(wrappedValue)
    }
  }

  /// - parameter emitCurrentValue: whether to emit the current wrapped value when subscribing to `projectValue`
  public init(wrappedValue: Value, emitCurrentValue: Bool = false) {
    self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    let didChangeSubject: any Subject<Value, Never>
    if emitCurrentValue {
      didChangeSubject = CurrentValueSubject(wrappedValue)
    } else {
      didChangeSubject = PassthroughSubject<Value, Never>()
    }
    self.didChangeSubject = didChangeSubject
    self.projectedValue = didChangeSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    self.valueDidChange = didChangeSubject.voidPublisher()
  }
}

public extension Publisher {
  /// Maps the `Output` of its upstream to `Void` and type erases its upstream to `AnyPublisher`.
  func voidPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Failure> {
    map { _ in Void() }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

You can observe a `@PostPublished` the same way you do a `@Published`.

```
class UsingPostPublished {
  @PostPublished var dontEmitInitial = 0
  @PostPublished(emitCurrentValue: true) var emitInitial = 0
}

private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let usingPostPublished = UsingPostPublished()
usingPostPublished.$dontEmitInitial.sink {
  print("dontEmitInitial did change to \($0)")
}.store(in: &cancellables)

usingPostPublished.$emitInitial.sink {
  print("emitInitial did change to \($0)")
}.store(in: &cancellables)

usingPostPublished.emitInitial = 1
usingPostPublished.dontEmitInitial = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a surprising design decision.  Anyone know of discussion ?

Comment: @orionelenzil since SwiftUI relies on `ObservableObject`'s `objectWillChange`, which emits whenever any `@Published` properties emit, `@Published` using `willSet` rather than `didSet` enables SwiftUI to prepare for view updates

Comment: Doesn't make sense that @publish uses will set, if that is the case, a swiftUI element say Text will no update once it receives the willset signal from the publisher as the published property is not updated during willset.

Comment: If SwiftUI is observing a @Published value, willSet causing the view to refresh, it will see the old value, not the didSet value.   Either that or the documentation isn't very clear on that part.

Comment: @mskw as I've said - you're _assuming_ this, but have you actually tried running the code and checking your assumptions? I have actually tested my arguments and can 100% confirm based on actual testing that `@Published` uses `willSet`. As I've said in comments, `objectWillChange` is used to prepare the View to update - it doesn't necessarily mean that the view immediately updates.

Comment: One important note about your implementation of `@PostPublished` is that it behaves a bit different from `@Published` (apart from firing on didset), as it doesn't seem to publish the current value when subscribed to. This can be achieved by changing this line: `self.projectedValue = didChangeSubject.prepend(wrappedValue).eraseToAnyPublisher()`

Comment: @MikkelSelsøe if you always want that behaviour, simply replace the `PassthroughSubject` with a `CurrentValueSubject`, no need to `prepend` any values. I've also updated my answer with a version of the code where this behaviour is customisable.

Answer (score 7):

Well I'll say use a simple hack

```
var test = Test()
var subscriber = test.$array
.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
.sink { values in
print("arrayCount: \(test.array.count) valuesCount: \(values.count)")
}
```

Comment: Specifying the dispatch queue postpones the sink until after the observed value is set.  Why is this answer downgraded?

Comment: Yes, why this answer is so downgraded?

Answer (score 6):

First, if the purpose is to have a publisher that emits events on didSet, then you can simply use `CurrentValueSubject`. Its syntax isn't as nifty as `@Published`, but it does the trick:

```
var array = CurrentValueSubject<[Int], Never>([])
// ...
let second = array.value[1]
// ...
array.sink {
    print("array count: $0.count")
}
array.send([1, 2, 3])
```

If you already have a `@Published` variable that you wish to keep (for example, your SwiftUI view uses it), but you also wish to observe changes also *after* they took place, then you can add a `CurrentValueSubject` and update it in `didSet`

```
class Test {
  @Published var array: [Int] = [] {
    didSet {
        arrayChangedEvent.send(array)
    }
  }
    var arrayChangedEvent = CurrentValueSubject<[Int], Never>([])
}
```

and then observe the array in much the same way: `arrayChangedEvent.sink { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Clever and best solution. Also, a `PassthroughSubject` may be enough for most.